# How to prevent / disable AST transformations in Groovy scripts?

Tags: java, security, groovy, code-injection

I'm using Groovy 3.x as my runtime scripting environment in my application. The user can enter scripts and extend the application in several ways. However, I need to prevent certain things; amongst them is shell access from such a script.

`CompileStatic` and blacklisting went a long way. However, the following [example](https://github.com/welk1n/exploiting-groovy-in-Java/blob/master/src/main/java/GroovyInjectionPayloads.java) shows a case not covered by static type checking and blacklisting. Assume that the user enters the following script:

```
@groovy.transform.ASTTest(value={
   assert java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("any evil shell command")
})
def x
```

The problem here is that the injection happens long before static type checking (which would prevent access to `Runtime`). And even worse: this can occur in all places where a statement (`def x`) is legal.

How can I prevent such injections with Groovy, specifically with the `GroovyClassLoader`?

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing (at least for now, I'm open to better suggestions) is:

- Before the script content is passed to the `GroovyClassLoader`...
- ... the script content is checked for annotations. This is done by:

  - replacing all string literals by empty string (`""`) with regular expressions
  - checking if the remaining string contains an `@` character
- If an `@` character is found in the script that does not reside in a string literal, the script is rejected and will not even be passed on to `GroovyClassLoader`.  Otherwise, the unmodified script is compiled.